# iphone - understanding crash logs

Tags: iphone

Im developing my app and yesterday while I was playing with it crashed. I wasnt debugging, so I thought I'd take a look at the crash log today.

But my surprise is that I can't see anything that can give me some info, here it is:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33479464 objc_msgSend + 16
1   MapKit                          0x31bffe28 -[MKMapView annotationContainer:viewForAnnotation:] + 36
2   MapKit                          0x31bffaba -[MKAnnotationContainerView _addViewForAnnotation:] + 270
3   MapKit                          0x31c25540 -[MKAnnotationContainerView addViewForManagedAnnotation:] + 8
4   MapKit                          0x31c21df2 -[MKMapView(UserPositioningInternal) _runPositioningChange] + 1034
5   MapKit                          0x31c20036 -[MKMapView(UserPositioningInternal) _startPositioningChange:] + 22
6   MapKit                          0x31c23446 -[MKMapView(UserPositioningInternal) locationManagerUpdatedLocation:] + 578
7   CoreFoundation                  0x33a5ebb8 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] + 16
8   CoreFoundation                  0x33a83266 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:] + 394
9   MapKit                          0x31c1232a -[MKLocationManager _reportLocationStatus:] + 34
10  MapKit                          0x31c13844 -[MKLocationManager _reportLocationSuccess] + 36
11  MapKit                          0x31c134b8 -[MKLocationManager locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:] + 688
12  CoreLocation                    0x34371410 -[CLLocationManager onClientEventLocation:] + 528
13  CoreLocation                    0x3436f68e -[CLLocationManager onClientEvent:supportInfo:] + 98
14  CoreLocation                    0x3436f7e6 OnClientEventInternal + 14
15  CoreLocation                    0x3436b534 CLClientInvokeCallback(__CLClient*, CLClientEvent, __CFDictionary const*) + 60
16  CoreLocation                    0x3436d3cc CLClientHandleDaemonDataLocation(__CLClient*, CLClientLocation const*, __CFDictionary const*) + 196
17  CoreLocation                    0x3436d512 CLClientHandleDaemonData(__CFMessagePort*, long, __CFData const*, void*) + 286
18  CoreFoundation                  0x33a813fe __CFMessagePortPerform + 242
19  CoreFoundation                  0x33a556f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
20  CoreFoundation                  0x33a556bc __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 160
21  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47f76 __CFRunLoopRun + 514
22  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
23  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
24  GraphicsServices                0x33b0e4a4 GSEventRunModal + 108
25  GraphicsServices                0x33b0e550 GSEventRun + 56
26  UIKit                           0x32099322 -[UIApplication _run] + 406
27  UIKit                           0x32096e8c UIApplicationMain + 664
28  Palyque                         0x0000280a main (main.m:14)
29  Palyque                         0x00002794 start + 44
```

Hope you can help me with this, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the app still in memory I'm not sure there's much you can do. From experience I guess you messaged an object that has been dealloc'd. (Maybe the datasource object for your MKMapView?) I'd try running your app with zombies enabled to track it down.

Comment: True story, it was the mapview, it was deallocated, but it was also expecting some data that it wasnt yet downloaded, and when it did it crashed badly.